# After updating computer enters in Emergency mode in KDE neon

Tags: fstab, journalctl, kde-neon

[image]I'm not sure if I'm posting in the right place. If it's so just let me know. Yesterday updated normally and when it rebooted it opens with the "emergency mode" and the "journalctl -xb" Been trying something's and the only thing I think it could be is that the fstab file got corrupted, because when I tried to open it with vim there was nothing written.

Tried to use boot repair and nothing.

Could enter in with live usb and the disks where there.

The thing is if someone knows what to do and help me with this. If you need more information I will try to get it.

I'm using KDE neon.

Greetings

Comment: AFAIK, KDE Neon is not meant to be used as a production Linux distribution - I remember it was only for testing purposes.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov They do have a User Edition *" Featuring the latest officially released KDE software on a stable base. Ideal for everyday users"*. https://neon.kde.org/download. David, is this what you have, or the Testing, Unstable or Dev edition?

Comment: Hi, I have the stable base. I think for about a year.